# Python: list length returned with twice of its length

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am reading a file witch contained `235886` strings in it. I am reading all these strings from the file by using `with` and appending them to an empty list. As each string in my file have a new line character `\n` appended, I am fetching only string by using `split()` function.

And when I print length of the list, it showing double of its size `471772`.

My code is here.

```
word_list = []
DICTIONARY =  'dictionary.txt'

def load_words():
    with open(DICTIONARY,'r') as dictwords :
        for word in dictwords:
            word_list.append(word.split('\n')[0])
        print(len(word_list))
    return word_list

load_words()
```

And output shows as

```
235886
471772
```

I am unable to find out where I am doing wrong. Any help, greatly appreciated.

#### Complete code

```
from data import DICTIONARY, LETTER_SCORES

word_list = []
scrabble_dict = {}

def load_words():

    with open(DICTIONARY,'r') as dictwords :
        for word in dictwords:
            word_list.append(word.split('\n')[0])
        print(len(word_list))
    return word_list

load_words()

def calc_word_value(word):
    sum = 0 
    for char in word:
        if char.isalpha():
            sum = sum + LETTER_SCORES[char.upper()]
    return sum

def max_word_value(word_list = load_words() ):
    higher_sum = 0 
    higher_word = None 

    for every_word in word_list:
        present_sum = calc_word_value(every_word)
        if present_sum > higher_sum:
            higher_word = every_word
            higher_sum = present_sum

    return higher_word


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    pass
```

Comment: Have you look what it inside your list ?

Comment: That can only happen if you call `load_words` twice.

Comment: @Exho Its solved. instead of doing outside of the function, I have emptied the list inside and its worked.

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question after you've already received answers. I'm rolling back that edit. (I'm not going to object to you posting your full code, mind you. Just don't post "fixed" code.)

Comment: @Aran-Fey, No my edits are my own edits but not from suggested answers.

Comment: It doesn't matter. "Fixing" your code means changing your question. Don't do that. If you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Ok sure. Thanks for letting me know. can I revert back to my edit ?

Comment: No, but you can post your real code (without the `word_list = []` in the function). Posting your complete code is ok. Changing the question so that it's about a different problem is not ok.

Comment: @Aran-Fey, Got you. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `load_words` twice and since `word_list` is a global variable, all the words are appended twice. Change it by storing the result of the first call in a variable:

```
l_words = load_words()

# ...

def max_word_value(word_list=l_words):
    # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I am not calling `max_word_value` function any where in my code, but still expression in function argument get evaluated ?

Comment: Yes, default arguments are evaluated and bound to the function at definition time.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, Python will evaluate it but will not put that block in run time but as evaluation is done, function called two times right ?